# On Overhead system calls

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

This was one of the question which I experienced in a exam .
The overhead for a process to perform a system call
that is like read() transfers data into a given array is much greater than when a process
calls an ordinary C function to do a similar thing. what are three things the kernel
or hardware must do for the system call that are not done for the ordinary function call

Comment: At least on x64 (32 and 64): Trap with ring change, CPU cache flush (or at least sync), memory remap.

Comment: Also depends how the OS implements system calls (i.e. on x86, may be interrupt, sysenter, etc.)

Comment: Please refer below link for the system call 

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/difference-between-system-calls-and-library-functions

Comment: The question makes no sense. The only reason a library function might be faster than a system call is that it may buffer the data. The library call eventually has to make the system call as well. The system call needs to trigger a fault, switch kernel mode, verify that the buffer is mapped to the process address space and that it is writeable in user mode.

Comment: What @user3344003 says.  The OS manages resources like disk I/O.  The C read/write is just a process-specific layer on top that can help with frequent reads of small data items by applying user-space buffering.